# What does it mean with bug report captured in android tablet?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-debug

I was playing around with my tablet and testing my program, when there was a notification that said bug report captured and whether I would like to share it. I had not seen this message before so I clicked Yes, and then I clicked OK on the warning dialog box that asked me to share it only with people I trust. After that the gmail app opened up which had a screenshot of my tablet, as well as a file attached to it called `bugreport<some numbers, date and time I think>.txt`. I did not send the bug report as I was not sure what it was and where it would go. However my question is,

what exactly is this bug report?

Is it generated by the code that I was testing? Or is it generated by the android system itself?

Did I trigger something unknowingly when I pressed the hardware buttons (the tablet only has 3 hardware buttons, volume up/down and power)?

I have been trying but I cannot make that message appear again, and when I search for bug*.txt using my file viewer app, I cannot find the file. Where is that .txt fil that got attached to the bug report get saved on my tablet?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's because you have turned on USB debugging in Developer Options. You can create a bug report by holding the power + both volume up and down.

**Edit**:
This is what the forums say:

> By pressing Volume up + Volume down + power button, you will feel a
>   vibration after a second or so, that's when the bug reporting
>   initiated.

To disable:

> /system/bin/bugmailer.sh must be deleted/renamed.

There should be a folder on your SD card called "bug reports".

Have a look at this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2252948

And this one: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1405639

Comment: I am trying but I can't make it happen again

Comment: where can I find the txt file and the screenshot that it had tried to attach before?

Comment: What device are using?

Comment: well I don't want to disable the feature as long as it notifies me and does not send any data on the Internet without my explicit permission. Thank you for your help

Comment: Anyway, I cannot find `/bugmailer.sh` in `/system/bin/`. And I cannot make the bugreport message appear again. but there does seem to be a file called `bugreport` in `/system/bin/`, but when I try to open it using a notepad like programi n my file explorer app, it just shows diamond symbols and few texts. It gives a warnign message that this file is encoded in Unicode and the text editor does not support Unicode

Comment: Maybe its to late and of little use for you, but the file you have found is a binary File. Probably the executable that generates the bug report.

Comment: Makes sense. I was trying to take a screenshot when this happened

Comment: This happened to me once, when I was trying to take a screenshot. For the record, there was a "Bug report captured" notification, then it said "Only share with people/apps you trust". After reading the above answer, I tried and failed to reproduce it; instead I managed to force-reboot my phone!  I won't be trying that again unless/until I have any use for these bug reports!

Comment: What if I don't have an SD card?