# How do I determine which app caused a BugReport on my Android Phone

Tags: android

I have a phone running Android 4.4.2. Once or twice a day I get a BugReport notification where I can email it to someone.  How do I determine which which app causes this crash? Is there something that can be read out of this to determine?

As a developer, I'm also curious if there is something I can do in my program to make sure that it is clear what app is crashing, and who it should be emailed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These notifications are happening because you have USB debugging enabled in the developer options - they are Android bug reports and not application specific. Typically if an app has crashed it will generate an ANR(Application Not Responding) dialogue and you will know which app caused it.

These reports themselves are stored on your SD card.

EDIT: related - [What does it mean with bug report captured in android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648353/what-does-it-mean-with-bug-report-captured-in-android-tablet)

Comment: So you think I'm hitting a hardware key combo to generate this?

Comment: Possibly. It could also be generated by unsuccesfully trying to take a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing 1 application at a time and waiting some amount of time to see if that is the one generating the error.

Comment: You mean uninstalling? I was hoping that there was something in the report or other area I could use rather then trial & error.

Comment: Yes, but its also possible you enabled the developer debugging options.

Comment: I did enable them, and it's probably why I'm seeing this, but how do I tell which app or service is crashing?

Comment: There should be a folder on your SD card called "bug reports".

Comment: Right, and I can email the reports to myself as they come up, but how do I determine in that file, which app crashed? Looking at it there was a ton of detail, but nothing jumped out as which app

Comment: The app name should be in there or at least an app version number. Using the version number you could then identify which app has the corresponding version.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for the answer to this question, but other than a guess, no one had *really* answered it. Additional searching and I found the answer [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/motorola-droid-maxx/361463-bug-report-captured.html): If you hold the volume-up and power keys, it will generate a bug report.

**So therefore nothing is crashing.** (sigh of relief)

I also thought something was crashing to generate this. I guess I need to figure out how to *not* let these keys get pressed when my phone is in my pocket.

Would be nice if the phone would disable these hotkeys — and the power key as well — while it's off and upside down. But that would be too useful.