# Android App is asking to share Bug report? Why is this?

Tags: android, android-alarms

I just learned Android from scratch and built an app with simple process using Android Studio.
The app has one process with repeating Alarm manager which will toast a message after 10 mins. That's it.

However, once I install it on a real device, after an hour or so, the device will ask to **Share Bug Report**. When I do share it,(via e-mail to my self), it is just a blank black screen..!
This happens with any device. I tried it on 3 devices so far. It is like:

- Device before my app: Normal functioning.
- Device after installing my app (after an hour or 2): A pop up comes
  up with 'Share bug report'.

PS: I have not written any code to call or share bug report or any popup.

Has anyone come across this strange behavior?? Any idea on what is happening here??

**EDIT 1:** It is not just a blank screen but there is a word doc with lengthy set of code. It basically contains the entire lump of data of entire system. Not just my app..!

Comment: Why down vote? I understand that some may not be able to answer or understand the question it self.. but down vote? Really?? Very helpful.. Thanks!!

Comment: Eureka! You just made something that steals System Data. Google is coming.

Comment: Bad joke @LancePreston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your app is freezing or stops responding.
Analyze your app logs, you will find the cause.

Did you read these threads ?

[What does it mean with bug report captured in android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648353/what-does-it-mean-with-bug-report-captured-in-android-tablet)

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-feedback-for-android.html

Comment: Wow!! This was all because I have turned the developer option and USB De-bugging in my device. (For testing). Thank you so much @Divya Y.  I really want to upvote but don't have enough repo to do so. Many thanks. This is the Correct answer if someone has similar concern. Refer to the links in this answer.

Comment: You are welcome, you can select this as right answer, if you feel thats ok. Meanwhile I will also suggest to check your app logs, something is going on in your app, which initiates the bug report.